# Asterisk / SIP - Delaying the 200 OK till after calling card is entered

Tags: asterisk, sip

Im trying to figure out a clever way to delay the 200 ok for the sip handshake till after the "please enter your calling card code" that my voip system will be transmitting to the incoming call..

Any thoughts on this..  I must admit, I';m looking at this conceptually at this point and am a bit naive...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to at least if you're planning on supporting standard SIP devices.

You can send early media to a device, such as your "please enter.." audio, with a 183 Session Progress Response but I can't see that being much use as the SIP calling device won't send any DTMF tones to the server until the call has been answered which requires the 200 Ok response.

Despite that I suspect you may be looking at the wrong thing. The 200 Ok from Asterisk is for the call between the caller and the Asterisk server to get the DTMF tones and determine whether the next call leg is authorised. Only after the calling card code is accepted does the next call leg start. It sounds like your problem is that users are noticing that the billable call time includes the time they spend entering their calling card PIN. Fiddling with the 200 Ok response is not the way to fix that. Trying to get Asterisk to generate a new CDR for the second call leg would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

For called party:

```
[main_content]

exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${NUM}@provider,,M(dialout-macro))

[macro-dialout-macro]
exten => s,1,Noop(here you should add detect of "please enter")
exten => s,n,Noop(some other commands go)
exten => s,n,MacroExit;we are ready to connect call.
```

For calling party - you need ALL your provider support early media and dtmf before answer. It is posible get provider which support early media, yes. But i not know any system which support dtmf before answer,sorry.

Dialplan will be like this

```
exten => _x.,1,Read(variable,filename,10,n,3)
```

note: no answer should be BEFORE that command, should be used option n

> n: to read digits even if the line is not up.

However as i say that will work only in theory.